# Get a substring after the last occurance of a string in Python

Tags: python

I have a string like:

```
test = "/home/myself/Downloads/example.py"
```

And I want to get the text after the last occurrence of `/`, which is `example.py`. I tried using split:

```
test.split("/")[0]
```

But the problem is that it would return the string with a fixed index, which I don't have usually.

How can I get the string after the last occurrence of /?

Comment: `test.split("/")[-1]`

Comment: As the string looks remarkably like a file path, maybe there is a function to extract the filename from it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `str.split` and get index `-1` which is the last element of the list.

```
test = "/home/myself/Downloads/example.py"
print(test.split("/")[-1]) # 'example.py'
```

Although, in the specific case of recovering a filename, the best approachis to use the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) module:

```
import os
test = "/home/myself/Downloads/example.py"
os.path.basename(test)  # -> example.py
```

Comment: Or `test.rsplit("/", 1)[-1]`

Comment: @jdehesa yea sure, there are probably thousands of small variation as how you can do that

Comment: @jdehesa, or using `pop` method which is faster than slicing.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut Does getting a single element actually count as slicing? How can `pop` be faster than getting one element of a list?

Comment: @jdehesa, i mean that pop is faster than slicing in case when you want the last item from one list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pop` method.

```
print(test.split("/").pop())
```

`pop` method is faster than `slicing`.

```
import timeit
t1 = timeit.Timer('test = "/home/myself/Downloads/example.py";test.split("/").pop()')
t2 = timeit.Timer('test = "/home/myself/Downloads/example.py";test.split("/")[-1]')
```

Output

```
t1 = 9.307525000622263e-07
t2 = 8.126347900179098e-06
```

Answer (score 2):

You can let [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) do it for you:

```
import os
test = "/home/myself/Downloads/example.py"
os.path.basename(test)  # -> example.py
```

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
test.split("/")[-1]
```

negative indices go backwards in lists in python so this accesses the last element

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are paths, you can also operate with them using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
p = Path("/home/myself/Downloads/example.py")
print(p.parts[-1])
# example.py
```